# Change Plot Output Based on checkboxInput Selection Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

**Overview**
Hello, I am trying to work with displaying different plots using checkboxes within tabsetPanels. I am working with a dynamic amount number of panels, so that is the reason for creating the UI contents within the server portion.

**Ideal Output**
For each tabPanel:

iris plot outputs if no checkboxes are selected

mtcars plot outputs if Box One is selected

islands plot outputs if Box Two is selected

sleep plot outputs if both Box One and Box Two are selected

**What I have tried**
-I have tried to use condtionalPanels to try to & capture the cases. I was under the impression that the value returns 'TRUE' if checked & 'FALSE' if unchecked, however I receive NULL for each of the boxed values, even if I set the default value to be checked.
-**I believe my underlying issue is my lack of ability to trigger the dynamic checkboxes for each tabPanel**

**Disclaimer**
This is a reproducible example, the default values of originally created tabPanels is set to 5. I did not accommodate proper code if the value were to change for the sake of simplicity.

Sample Code:

```
ui <- navbarPage(title="Dynamic tabsetPanels",id="navbar",
                 tabPanel("Home",
                          textInput(inputId = "numPanels",
                                    label = "Enter # of Panels to produce",
                                    value = 5)
                 ),tabPanel("Analysis",
                            tabsetPanel(id = "tabs"))
) 
  server <- function(input, output) {
    plotOne = renderPlot({plot(iris)})
    plotTwo = renderPlot({plot(mtcars)})
    plotThree = renderPlot({plot(islands)})
    plotFour = renderPlot({plot(sleep)})
    observe({
      req(input$numPanels)
      lapply(1:input$numPanels,function(i){
        tabName = paste("Tab",i,sep=" ")
        first = paste0("first",i)
        second = paste0("second",i)
        appendTab(inputId = "tabs",
                  tab = tabPanel(
                    tabName,
                    fluidPage(
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          #side-panel code
                          h2("Features"),
                          checkboxInput(inputId=first,label="Box One"),
                          checkboxInput(inputId=second,label="Box Two")
                        ),mainPanel(
                          #output when nothing clicked
                          conditionalPanel(
                            condition = "!glue(input.{first} && !glue(input.{second})",
                            plotOutput(iris)
                          ),
                          #output when box one is clicked
                          conditionalPanel(
                            condition = "glue(input.{first})",
                            plotOutput(mtcars)
                          ),
                          #output when box two is clicked
                          conditionalPanel(
                            condition = "glue(input.{second})",
                            plotOutput(islands)
                          ),
                          #output when box one and two are clicked
                          conditionalPanel(
                            condition = "glue(input.{first}) && glue(input.{second})",
                            plotOutput(sleep)
                          )
                        )
                      )
                    )
                  )
                  )
      })
    })
  }
  shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue with your code is the use of `glue` to create your conditions, i.e. you have to do e.g. `condition = glue("input.{first}")` instead of `condition = "glue(input.{first})"` to evaluate the glue string. Second issue is that in the `plotOutputs` you have to use the names of the outputs, e.g. `plotOutput("plotOne")` instead of `plotOutput(iris)`. Finally, even after fixing these issues your app will not work as desired as you can't use outputs with the same `id` in several places or tabs, i.e. you get a duplicated id error. To fix that you also have to create a dynamic list of outputs so that the ids are unique.

```
library(shiny)
library(glue)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "Dynamic tabsetPanels", id = "navbar",
  tabPanel(
    "Home",
    textInput(
      inputId = "numPanels",
      label = "Enter # of Panels to produce",
      value = 5
    )
  ), tabPanel(
    "Analysis",
    tabsetPanel(id = "tabs")
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    req(input$numPanels)
    lapply(1:input$numPanels, function(i) {
      output[[paste0("plotOne", i)]] <- renderPlot(plot(iris))
      output[[paste0("plotTwo", i)]] <- renderPlot(plot(mtcars))
      output[[paste0("plotThree", i)]] <- renderPlot(plot(islands))
      output[[paste0("plotFour", i)]] <- renderPlot(plot(sleep))
    })
  })
  
  observe({
    req(input$numPanels)
    lapply(1:input$numPanels, function(i) {
      tabName <- paste("Tab", i, sep = " ")
      first <- paste0("first", i)
      second <- paste0("second", i)
      appendTab(
        inputId = "tabs",
        tab = tabPanel(
          tabName,
          fluidPage(
            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(
                # side-panel code
                h2("Features"),
                checkboxInput(inputId = first, label = "Box One"),
                checkboxInput(inputId = second, label = "Box Two")
              ), mainPanel(
                # output when nothing clicked
                conditionalPanel(
                  condition = glue("!input.{first} && !input.{second}"),
                  plotOutput(paste0("plotOne", i))
                ),
                # output when box one is clicked
                conditionalPanel(
                  condition = glue("input.{first}"),
                  plotOutput(paste0("plotTwo", i))
                ),
                # output when box two is clicked
                conditionalPanel(
                  condition = glue("input.{second}"),
                  plotOutput(paste0("plotThree", i))
                ),
                # output when box one and two are clicked
                conditionalPanel(
                  condition = glue("input.{first} && input.{second}"),
                  plotOutput(paste0("plotFour", i))
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    })
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: I will admit my reproducible example had some flaws. I was able to solve the issue within my personal project, which was the conditionalPanels not triggering correctly. Thanks for the help!